# Problem with Python 3.1(syntax error). Im a beginner please help!

Tags: python

im new to pragraming :)
I got a problem with sytax error while making a guessing game. the problem is in (if Gender = boy or Boy), the equal(=) letter is a syntax error. Please help!

```
Answer = 23

Guess = ()

Gender = input("Are you a boy, a girl or an alien? ")


if Gender = boy or Boy:

    print("Nice!", Gender)
if Gender = girl or Girl:

    print("Prepare do die!", Gender)
if Gender = alien or Alien:

    print("AWESOME my", Gender, "Friend!")


While Guess != Answer:

    if Guess < Answer:

        print("Too low! try again")

        else:

            print("too high!"

print("Congratulations you guessed correct!", Gender, "Have fun!"
```

Thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write them like this:

```
if Gender in ('boy', 'Boy'):

if Gender in ('girl', 'Girl'):
```

And `=` is assignment operator, not equality and that is why the error is there. Either ways, use the `in` method of comparing.

```
if Gender in options
```

where `options` is a tuple.

Or if you want to stick to your method:

```
if Gender == 'boy' or Gender == 'something else'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong:

1. = is the assignment operator, not the equality test operator. That's ==
2. When you use or, you must have two complete statements.

```
if Gender == boy or Gender == Boy:
    print("you are a boy.")
```

1. I'm assuming you want boy/Boy as strings (same with girl/Girl). They must be wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

you are using the '=' operator to test equality.  You need to use '==' instead.

you are also comparing to a variable, when I think you meant the string "boy"

how about this?:

```
if Gender.lower() == "boy":
    print("Nice!", Gender)
```